# How to parse phone numbers from multiple html's?

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing

I don't know how to parse phone numbers from multiple html's, because they have different name in ***span class***. I have only one idea, it s to parse full html text and using regex to get phone number, but i have about 1000 html's and i think that it will spend a lot of time

I know how to parse single html page using BeautifulSoup

```
r = requests.get(Base_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.find("div", class_="some_class").find("span", class_="phone number").text
```

Comment: If you don't know where the phone numbers could be located, a regex is probably the best solution. It shouldn't take very long to parse 1000 htmls

Comment: Give us several html examples

Comment: @Alderven [link](https://www.pik.ru/) [link](https://a101.ru/) [link](https://xn--b1agamajcgnffd6c6gva.xn--p1ai/)